# How to use the qsub -v command in PBS torque with a perl script?

Tags: perl, pbs, qsub, torque

I would like to pass variables to a perl script by using "qsub -v" command. 
This is the perl script I would run (it's just a test but if it doesn't work I cannot do anything more difficult)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Getopt::Long;
$result = GetOptions ("i=s" => \$config_file);

open(FILE,">/data/home/FILEout.txt");
open(FILE_CONFIG,"<$config_file");
while(<FILE_CONFIG>){
  print FILE "$config_file\n";
}
close(FILE_CONFIG);
close(FILE);
```

So, if I would run this script (not through qsub) I would type:

```
perl Test.pl -i FILE_CONFIG.txt
```

However I would run this script on a node of a cluster that works with pbs. 
I have done several attemp like the following one:

```
qsub -l nodes=node06 -v i=/data/home/FILE_CONFIG.txt Test.pl
```

but it doesn't work.
Anyone as an idea how I should pass the parameter to my perl script using qsub?
Any help would be really appreciated

Doesn't work means that using qsub doesn't print nothing on the output file while using just perl it print the content of the input file in the output file. It looks like it doesn't take nothing in input

Comment: Yes I'm sorry. Is exactly the same. I've corrected it. Doesn't work means that using qsub doesn't print nothing on the output file while using just perl it print the content of the nput file in the output file.
It looks like it doesn't take nothing in input

Comment: Yes I did it but it doesn't work. I'm just able to run a perl file using the following instruction: `qsub -l nodes=node06 Test.pl`. But I'm not able to specify any input. I tried with perl before Test.pl and it doesn't work. I also tried to use -S and if I use `qsub -l nodes=node06 -S /usr/bin/perl Test.pl` it works, however if I specify also the input parameters (`qsub -l nodes=node06 -S /usr/bin/perl Test.pl -i FILE_CONFIG.txt`) it doesn't work anymore. What should I do? Please help

Comment: The -v a=b in qsub doesn't pass a=b as an argument to the script, its sets the environment variable a with the value b in the environment for the job. In your script, you'd need to read them from the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be easier for you to submit the job this way:

```
echo "perl /absolute/path/to/Test.pl -i FILE_CONFIG.txt" | qsub -l nodes=node06
```

Then, as long as you know that Test.pl is in the path you specify on node06, it should work correctly.

Comment: +1. Note that one situation where this will not work as expected is if the Test.pl script itself contains embedded `#PBS` directives. The solution to _that_ problem is basically just not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The [`qsub` command](http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs/commands/qsub.shtml) does not allow command line arguments to be directly passed to the input script.  There are two basic ways around that:

1. Write a wrapper script that calls your actual script with the appropriate arguments.  You can even pass the wrapper script to `qsub` on the standard input, as shown in [dbeer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15686085), by specifying the script name in the `qsub` command as "`-`" or omitting it entirely.

   Note that, if you do this, any embedded `#PBS` directives must be specified in the *wrapper* script, not in the inner script called by the wrapper.  Of course, if you're not using that particular feature, then you don't need to worry about it.
2. Pass the arguments through the environment instead, using the `-v` switch to `qsub`.  That is, if your `qsub` command looks like this:

   ```
   qsub -l nodes=node06 -v CONFIG=/data/home/FILE_CONFIG.txt Test.pl
   ```

   then your `Test.pl` script can read the configuration file path from `$ENV{CONFIG}`, like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my $config = $ENV{CONFIG} || 'default_config_file_path.txt';
   open CONFIG, '<', $config  or die "Error opening $config: $!\n";

   # ... rest of script here ...
   ```

Comment: Thanks!!! Also this solution worked well and it fit better my needs. I really appreciate @llmari Karonen